# List of Print SDK for iPhone/ iPad or iOS except AirPrint SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, printing, sdk, airprint

I want a list Print SDKs for printing a document,pdf or image through iPhone or iPad.

I know Apple is providing AirPrint SDk from iOS 4.2 or later, but I want to know if any other 3rd party Paid or free Print SDKs are available for printing documents ? One SDK i know ZebraLink Multiplatform SDK but it support some limited printers.

If any one know other SDKs than please share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the Google Cloud Print API at http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.kite.ly have a dedicated iOS print SDK which may work for you depending on your exact use case. You would be paying for every document you print (paper + postage) though but it does remove the need to have a printer in the first place i.e. you don't need any infrastructure.

- iOS Print SDK: https://github.com/OceanLabs/iOS-Print-SDK

[image]

Full disclosure: I'm cofounder of the company so a little biased, but our products and offerings also happen to be really really good (especially from a developer integration point of view) so I'll take any chance to shout about it ;) We also built it to solve our own problems like yours so it's definitely applicable!

We're primarily about high quality, beautiful personalised products such as Photo Prints, Magnets, Postcards, Posters, Stickers, Phone cases, etc. but can do regular document printing as per your question.

We also have:

- REST Print API: https://www.kite.ly/docs/1.1/
- Android Print SDK: https://github.com/OceanLabs/Android-Print-SDK

Several of our partners also have millions of users hitting our services so you'll be in good company!

/end shameless plug ;)

Comment: website broken - I am not trusting them with my name

Comment: @JeshuaLacock really sorry about that, can you point me in the direction of the issue you encountered?